# Why can't I get the resolution i want

Tags: python, pytube

This thing not download my videos in the highest resolution

```
from pytube import YouTube

link = input("video linki: \n>> ")
yt = YouTube(link)

video = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
video.download()

print(yt.title + " successfuly downloaded")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the [documentation](https://pytube.io/en/latest/user/streams.html). `get_highest_resolution` works only for *progressive streams* up to 720p. Youtube now uses a techinque called DASH, which means that you need to download the video and audio streams separately for the highest quality.